# A sha value represent to the status for git repository

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

There is a sha value represent to the status for git repository in current status?

The sha value to be updated each time the Object Database updated and References changed if git has this sha value.

In other words, the sha value represent to the current version of whole repository.

Here is my code for calculate a sha for current references. There is a git level API or interface?

```
private string CalcBranchesSha(bool includeTags = false)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(":HEAD");
    if (_repository.Head.Tip != null)
        sb.Append(_repository.Head.Tip.Sha);
    sb.Append(';');
    foreach (var branch in _repository.Branches.OrderBy(s => s.Name))
    {
        sb.Append(':');
        sb.Append(branch.Name);
        if (branch.Tip != null)
            sb.Append(branch.Tip.Sha);
    }
    sb.Append(';');
    if (includeTags)
    {
        foreach (var tag in _repository.Tags.OrderBy(s => s.Name))
        {
            sb.Append(':');
            sb.Append(tag.Name);
            if (tag.Target != null)
                sb.Append(tag.Target.Sha);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString().CalcSha();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean current version of the code or repository?

Comment: Which one? If you what the code just take the hash of the most recent commit. A commit includes a hash of the parent.

Comment: I know each commit, tree, blob, gitlink have the sha. But I need a sha  for whole repository.

Comment: It doesn't have one but every commit should be reachable from a tag or branch so you're code seems the best best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a sha value represent to the status for git repository in current status?

In git parlance, the status of a repository usually refers to the paths that have differences between the working directory, the index and the current HEAD commit.

However, it doesn't look like you're after this. From what I understand, you're trying to calculate a checksum that represents the state of the current repository (ie. what your branches and tags point to).

Regarding the code, it may be improved in some ways to get a more precise checksum:

- Account for all the references (beside `refs/tags` and `refs/heads`) in the repository (think `refs/stash`, `refs/notes` or the generated backup references in `refs/original` when one rewrite the history of a repository).
- Consider disambiguating symbolic from direct references. (ie: `HEAD->master->08a4217` should lead to a different checksum than `HEAD->08a4127`)

Below a modified version of the code which deals with those two points above, by leveraging the `Refs` namespace:

```
private string CalculateRepositoryStateSha(IRepository repo)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append(":HEAD");
    sb.Append(repo.Refs.Head.TargetIdentifier);
    sb.Append(';');

    foreach (var reference in repo.Refs.OrderBy(r => r.CanonicalName))
    {
        sb.Append(':');
        sb.Append(reference.CanonicalName);
        sb.Append(reference.TargetIdentifier);
        sb.Append(';');
    }

    return sb.ToString().CalcSha();
}
```

**Please keep in mind the following limits:**

- This doesn't consider the changes to the index or the workdir (eg. the same checksum will be returned either a file has been staged or not)
- There are ways to create object in the object database without modifying the references. Those kind of changes won't be reflected with the code above. One possible hack-ish way to do this could be to also append to the `StringBuuilder`, the number of object in the object database (ie. `repo.ObjectDatabase.Count()`), but that may hinder the overall performance as this will enumerate all the objects each time the checksum is calculated).

> There is a git level API or interface?

I don't know of any equivalent native function in git (although similar result may be achieved through some scripting). There's nothing native in libgit2 or Libgit2Sharp APIs.

Comment: More question, Does I need to sort the references name?

Comment: Good point! The order in which the refs are retrieved depends on the way the underlying storage outputs them. Ordering them would make my proposal more robust. Thanks for having noticed this. I'll update the answer shortly to reflect this.